# PMF of the number of Statistics majors in the sample

Tags: probability, combinatorics

There are n students at a certain school, of whom X ⇠ Bin(n, p) are Statistics majors.A simple random sample of size m is drawn (“simple random sample” means sampling without replacement, with all subsets of the given size equally likely).

a)Find the PMF of the number of Statistics majors in the sample, using the law of total probability (don’t forget to say what the support is). You can leave your answer as a sum (though with some algebra it can be simplified, by writing the binomial coefficients in terms of factorials and using the binomial theorem).
Can somebody help me to solve the problem? I can't really uderstand how to implement LTP in this case.

b) Give a story proof derivation of the distribution of the number of Statistics majors in the sample; simplify fully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let X = k be a random variable representing the no of statistics majors in the randomly drawn sample of size m.
As far as dividing the sample into multiple cases is concerned for using the LOTP, Let's assume the **total no. of statistics majors**(TS) belong to [0, n] in the original sample for each case.

P(X=k) = P(X =K|TS = 0)*P(TS = 0) + P(X=k|TS=1)*P(TS=1)+ ......+ P(X=k|TS=n)*P(TS=n)

Each of the conditional part i.e. P(X=k|TS=1) is a hypergeometric distribution and P(TS=1) is Bin(n,p)

Comment: Were you able to solve the b part of this question? As per my understanding, students declaring their majors before/ after being chosen in the random sample of size m does not matter. Thus, choosing m students out of n with n choose m ways and then P(X=k) = (m choose k) p^k * (1-p)^(m-k)

Comment: Sorry, the solution to b part seems wrong to me, however it would be great to know the solution if you have solved it.